# UnicodeDecodeError when uploading image bytes to Azure Block Blob via Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, encoding, sdk

I am using the [Azure Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blobservice.py) to upload an image file as an Azure Block Blob.  I'd like to use the "put_block_blob_from_bytes" method, and not the "put_block_blob_from_file" method.

I am getting the following error on the last line of code:

"UnicodeDecodeError was unhandled by user code
Message: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

It seems I need to change the content encoding to "utf-8" somewhere, but I can't figure out the correct place to put this in the method signature for "[put_block_blob_from_bytes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blobservice.py)".

I tried this, but still receive the same error:

```
blob_service.put_block_blob_from_bytes("testcontainer", "myimage.png", data, 0, None, "utf-8")
```

Here is the full code sample.  Note: I removed the storage account name and key for the sake of publishing.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
azureStorageAccountName = "" # REMOVED for this question
azureStorageAccountKey = "" # REMOVED for this question
with open("c:\\temp\\image.png", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    blob_service = BlobService(account_name=azureStorageAccountName, account_key=azureStorageAccountKey)
    blob_service.put_block_blob_from_bytes("testcontainer", "myimage.png", data)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I just tried the same code with a file on my computer (it's a Windows 8 machine) and it worked just fine. Can you share more details? Like SDK version etc.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav!  I ran "pip install azure --upgrade", which changed the error message to say that the container didn't exist; I then added blob_service.create_container("testcontainer"), ran it again, and it worked.

Comment: I just confirmed the container issue was unrelated.  So the root cause was that I had an older SDK that had the issue.

Comment: Broken link https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/blobservice.py

Answer (score 1):

I ran:

```
pip install azure --upgrade
```

Which upgraded a few components.  I then ran it again, and everything worked.  Thanks to Gaurav Mantri for the tip to ensure I had the latest version of the SDK.